# smallest poisitive integer does not belong in floating point system F

Tags: number-systems, floating-point

A floating-point number system F is a subset of real numbers whose elements have the form:

$x=\pm(m/\beta^t)\beta^e$

base (beta), precision (t), and exponent range (emin and emax). The mantissa m and the exponent e are integers.

with $1\le m\le \beta^t$

what is the smallest positive integer does not belong in floating point system F?

could you please help?

Comment: As written it would be $0$, but once you fix that, $\beta^t+1$ would sound like a good guess. (Assuming that by "small" you mean "close to zero"; otherwise there are an infinity of unrepresentable _negative_ integers that are smaller).

Comment: i need the positive integer. could you please explain why it is $\beta^t +1$

Comment: x @104: You might see if you can prove that every representable number greater than $\beta^t$ is an integer multiple of $\beta$.

Comment: then the answer is clear. ok, i'll try to prove it. thanks

Comment: but how do would i know that the smaller integers are in F?

Comment: to not represent some integers, we need $\beta^{e-t}$ to be larger than 1. in this case the smallest e is t+1. so we have $x=m.\beta$

Comment: am I on the right track?

Comment: x @104: Yes. And choosing $e=t$ obviously gives you all of the smaller nonzero integers (some of them in denormalized form, but your definition doesn't seem to have a problem with that).

Comment: so, e is not fixed. it can take multiple values

Comment: x @104: Correct. $t$ is a constant for the floating-point system, but $e$ is part of the representation of a particular number and an be chosen between $e_{\rm min}$ and $e_{\rm max}$. It is assumed that $-e_{\rm min}$ and $e_{\rm max}$ are both fairly large compared to $t$.